# Writing in files

Tags: python-2.7, file

I have been trying to write onto a file while using python but for some reason it keeps writing onto my console and not my created file. Yes I know this question has been asked before and yes i have used the .close() command. Here is my block of code.

```
myfile= open ('C:/Users/12345/Documents/Grouped_data.txt','r')

with open ('C:/Users/12345/nanostring.txt','w') as output:

    for line in myfile:
        Templist= line.split()
        print line
        print Templist[0], Templist[4], Templist[5],Templist[6], Templist[7], Templist[8], Templist[9], Templist[10], Templist[12] 
        print output
myfile.close()
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as:

```
>>> with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
...     the_file.write('Hello\n')
```

From The Documentation:

> Do not use `os.linesep` as a line terminator when writing files opened in text mode (the default); use a single '\n' instead, on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7,

You can use `>>` after the `print` and use `as name`

So here it is `print>>output,line`

```
myfile= open ('C:/Users/12345/Documents/Grouped_data.txt','r')
with open ('C:/Users/12345/nanostring.txt','w') as output:
    for line in myfile:
        Templist= line.split()
        print>>output,line # Note the changes
        print>>output,Templist[0], Templist[4], Templist[5],Templist[6], Templist[7], Templist[8], Templist[9], Templist[10], Templist[12] # Note the changes
```

Note: `print` directly prints in terminal and `print>>as name,` prints to file.